# References request: are there some references about simple modules of group algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

Are there some references about constructing the simples, determining the dimensions of simple modules and describing decompositions of tensor products of simple modules of group algebras? Thank you very much.

Comment: Such "simple modules" are known as irreducible representations, no?

Comment: @anon, yes, simple modules are irreducible representations.

Comment: Which field are you working on?  For characteristic zero, use ATLAS of finite simple group (+basic character theory) extensively.  Otherwise, it's an extremely difficult question in general.  People tackle it case by case, as far as I know.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you very much. Are there some references about the case by case studies?